# Define a user role by it's id and who modify a schema : Oracle

Tags: oracle

I've got an Oracle database (SYSTEM) with two schema (database_A, database_B).
I need to create a user role (app_user) who can modify his schema. But he can only be on database_A or database_B and modify where he is and we can find this user on a table "user" (database_A.user, database_B.user). So how can i create a role like this ?

If i define a user role :

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON database_A to app_user;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON database_B to app_user;
```

The role will automatically define where the user can modify ?
Have you got documentation for this problem ?

Thanks for your answers,

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do. Anyway: here's documentation about CREATE ROLE (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-ROLE.html#GUID-B2252DC5-5AE7-49B7-9048-98062993E450), **follow** links at the beginning of the page, especially **Oracle Database Security Guide for general information about roles**.

Comment: My problem is, i don't know how create a role by user id and give him access on the database where is he